# Is this the correct way of downloading a file with ASIHTTPRequest?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, asihttprequest

Is this the correct way of downloading a file with ASIHTTPRequest? As you can see, I'm trying to download the file to the documents directory and am naming Test.mov. The only part is... the file doesn't download. I'm still confused by how ASIHTTPRequest works, so all help is appreciated!

```
-(IBAction)download {

    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.chillysky.com/Test.mov"]];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Test.mov", documentsDirectory];

    [request setDownloadDestinationPath:file];
    [request setDownloadProgressDelegate:myProgressIndicator];
    [request setDelegate:self];

    NSLog(@"Downloading File");

}
```

Comment: BTW, the author of ASIHTTPRequest has ceased development on it and recommends users find another HTTP client library to use. Tragic, but it happens. I'm between projects at the moment so it's a good opportunity for some research about alternatives.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Is there any other library that you would suggest that's as easy to use as ASIHTTPRequest (new to network stuff)?

Comment: Nope. Still in shock that my favorite library is closing shop. (I also haven't started a new project recently, so haven't had the occasion to look around.) His blog lists a few options. http://allseeing-i.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! Forgot this code:

```
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: You should avoid synchronous network calls, as this will lead to blocking

Comment: ie. use [request startAsyncronous] instead