# Download / retrieve pdf with asihttprequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, download, storage

I'm trying to download content with an URL to a local file system in my iPad (cachedDir ? )
with this function:

```
- (IBAction)download:(id)sender {

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:www.google.de"];

ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/my_file.pdf"]; // Which //directory??

}
```

Which directory do I have to choose for my path if I want to store the data as long as possible without getting rejected by Apple,
and how do I retrieve the data I've saved?

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

The best place to store documents that you want to keep around is your application's Documents directly. You can find the path to it like so:

```
// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

Apple have a useful piece of documentation about the iOS file system and where to store particular types of files: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Answer (score 0):

Try out this my code for save pdf in document using below code

```
NSString *downloadUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:www.google.de"];
 NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:downloadUrl]];

  //Store the Data locally as PDF File

 NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];
  NSString *pdf1 = @"title.pdf";
  NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:pdf1];

 [pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

and retrive your file using

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSURL *pdfURL = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:[paths objectAtIndex:0]] URLForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"title.pdf"] withExtension:nil];
    NSLog(@"pDF URl %@", pdfURL);

    pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
```

Comment: thx for the code by now, but the code shows an synchronous download or? i forgot to say that it should be asynchronous

Comment: then follow the link of asynchronous download http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103308/how-to-monitor-pdf-download-process-in-iphone-sdk/12103472#comment16178593_12103472

Comment: mho this download function is hard for me 2 customize, also because i don't have a progress indicator showing up

Comment: ok then do one thing remove self.av and remove sentences of myProgressIndicator it's not affect to your task

Comment: can't set @property (nonatomic, retain) ASIHTTPRequest *rqstForAudio;        without getting error "unknown type name" :/

Comment: what about this function? seems more straight forward                   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116555/is-this-the-correct-way-of-downloading-a-file-with-asihttprequest?rq=1